# Talbot-Lau effect to investigate decoherence of fullerene

Tags: optics, waves, decoherence

I am reading [Decoherence and the Quantum-To-Classical Transition](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540357735), which describes the experiment of investigating the dynamic of decoherence by making interference of fullerene molecules. Such experiment is described in [this paper](https://www.univie.ac.at/qfp/publications3/pdffiles/2002-04.pdf) and is based on Talbot-Lau effect.

The principle of Talbot-Lau effect is that if you send wave through diffraction slit having spacing $d$, you know that if you put a screen at a distance $L_{\lambda}=\frac{d^2}{\lambda}$, you will see the reproduction of the slits pattern. To know if it is indeed due to some wave interference (and not simply because ray were blocked), if you change your screen of position, you will see that the slits pattern is not reproduced slightly before and after. Thus it is indeed due to wave interference (that's how I simply understand it at least).

Such effect is then used in the experiment will fullerene, the wave nature comes from the wavefunction. What you want to see is that by increasing the temperature of the environment, you "break" the wave nature of the fullerene and thus you kill the interference pattern.

What I do not understand is that to see this effect, they basically study the visibility as a function of environmental pressure $V(p)=\frac{c_{max}(p)-c_{min}(p)}{c_{max}(p)+c_{min}(p)}$. What is explained in [Decoherence and the Quantum-To-Classical Transition](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540357735) is that when the decoherence won't have happened, $c_{min}=0$ and the visibility will be maximum. But when decoherence occurs $c_{min}=c_{max}$ and thus $V=0$.

**I don't understand this last thing**. For me the difference between wavy and not wavy **can only be observed if one move the screen from its fixed position $L_{\lambda}$**. If one exactly look at $L_{\lambda}$ it is impossible to know if the "interference" pattern is due to wave effect or simply to the fact that particles propagated classically and of course they will impact behind a slit, only which would reproduce the image of the slits. But it won't be due to interference effect but simply classical behavior.

How to clarify all this ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the screen, the authors of the paper seem to have moved the third grating in their experiment, see Fig. 2 in the linked paper. The figure shows a "single scan", thus presumably for a single pressure. For fully incoherent processes, there will simply be no oscillations and $V=0$, as stated by the OP.

One such plot is then recorded for each setting of the mean molecular beam velocity and the visibility is read off by identifying the minima and maxima of the curve. Fig. 3 seems to show the results of such a scan.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the time I wrote this question I better understood the experiment. They do not vary the position of the screen (along the longitudinal axis), but rather the wavelength of the particle (through their velocities), which in the end gives the same result. However a thing that puzzle me is that in the classical regime I would not expect $V=0$. The only thing I would expect is the visibility being independant of lambda. Indeed if you send marbles through slits, you see max and min corresponding to "hole" and "wall" of the slits. This is the last thing that confuses me

Comment: @StarBucK I guess this depends on the definition of V, in particular which parameter you scan. Let's take a simpler example: the double slit. As you say, you would still have minima and maxima across the screen for particles. However, if you move the screen away, the change in the pattern is very different. The particle maxima would move along lines, since they behave like rays. Also the number of maxima would change. In this experiment, it is similar. They scan the right parameter.